# MongoDB order by _id using Lua

Tags: mongodb, lua, sql-order-by

I create an API using Lua for query data from MongoDB.

```
for q_result in q_out:results() do
    test_query = "{'a_id': '"..q_result.a_id.."' , 'b_id':'"..bid.."'}"
    local rq = assert(db:query('DBName.table', test_query))
```

Now its order by descending, I find a way to order by ascending.

I see [this link](http://code.google.com/p/luamongo/source/browse/trunk/mongo_connection.cpp#277) but I don't know how to write a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested way to do this is [this](http://getmoai.com/forums/how-to-sort-queries-t460/):

```
client.db:query( 'users' , { query={ firstName='Ezra' },
  orderby={ lastName=1, firstName=1 } } )
```

I don't this your query is going to work. You are creating a string and it needs to be a table. Probably something like this:

```
local test_query = {query = {a_id = q_result.a_id, b_id = bid}}
test_query.orderby = {a_id=1} -- 1 sort ascending, -1 sort descending.
```

Comment: ahhh I try your code but still doesn't work.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: doesn't work in what way? Returns an error? Doesn't sort? Sorts in incorrect order?

Comment: I'm confusing because now I use a json_string to query all in my code.

Comment: I try to adapt your code to mine but it still syntax error. I am new for Lua.